# How to specialize a class in Ruby that can only be instantiated via a factory?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, instantiation, factory

I have a class, *L* from a library that can only be instantiated via a factory method, *L.factory*. I would like to be able to specialize it via inheritance. So we have:

```
class L
  attr_accessor :g

  def self.factory
    l = L.new
    l.g = "magic"
    l
  end
end

class S < L
  def self.new
    allocate
    l = L.factory
    # is there a way to return a class S object here with data from l?
  end

  def g2
    "my #{g}"
  end
end

s = S.new
s.g       #==>  "magic"
s.g2      #==>  fails because s.class is L
```

Comment: Why not use delegation instead of inheritance? Make S have an L and delegate all methods to that except the ones you provide. [SimpleDelegator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) makes this kinda thing easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion, if you can't modify the code in L, what you can do might be ugly "copy and paste" code from L to S. It is ugly due to code duplicated.

```
class L
  attr_accessor :g

  def self.factory
    l = L.new
    l.g = "magic"
    l
  end
end

class S < L
  def self.new
    obj = allocate
    obj.g = "magic" #copy and paste from L
    obj
  end

  def g2
    "my #{g}"
  end
end

s = S.new
s.g       #==>  "magic"
s.g2      #==>  "my magic"
```

update:

@dbenhur really gives a good suggestion. Following code is implemented considering his suggestion.

```
require 'delegate'

class L
  attr_accessor :g

  def self.factory
    l = L.new
    l.g = "magic"
    l
  end
end

class S < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize
    super(L.factory)
  end

  def g2
    "my #{g}"
  end
end

s = S.new
p s.g       #==>  "magic"
p s.g2      #==>  "my magic"
```

Comment: Indeed, that works, and answers the question. And you can do some Object#instance_variable introspection to make it work in the general case. That _is_ pretty ugly though, you're right :). I think I would end up preferring object aggregation and delegation as suggested by @dbenhur over this.

Comment: Considering @dbenhur's suggestion, I got a new solution. Please take a look, the post has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

To make that kind of stuff work, you mustn't hard-code the class names.

```
class Parent
  def self.factory
    allocate
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def self.new
    factory
  end
end

p Parent.new
p Child.new
```

Comment: Don't we override the `initialize` methods of classes. When do we override the `new` method of a class?

Comment: @Chandranshu: Yes, you will. `allocate` basically does what you said: allocate without calling `initialize`. But as I understand it, that is more or less what OP wants — he'd like objects to be pulled from his factory.

Comment: That works for the example above, where the factory is a member of the class L, but what if the factory belongs to a different class? In my case I am trying to specialize Mongo::GridIO, which is accessed via Mongo::GridFS#get.

Comment: I'm puzzled... What's the problem with making `Mongo::GridFS#get` return `Mongo::GridIO.new`?

Comment: I want to construct a subclass (S in the example) of Mongo::GridIO (L in the example), that calls Mongo::GridFS#get as part of it's initialization.

Comment: I think you should edit your question accordingly, or add a new question that mentions mongo explicitly. Asked the way it currently is, I'm afraid it's not clear what you're after, sorry.